# Azure Devops - Service Principal manual (or) Service Principal automatic for production deployments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

What is recommended for the Azure devops service connection, when would I go for Service Principal manual (or) Service Principal automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both ok, the differences are like blew, just choose one to use depending on your preference.

- `Service Principal (automatic)`: It will [create an AD App along with the service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) in Azure AD for you automatically and use it in the service connection.
- `Service Principal (manual)`: You need to [create the AD App along with the service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) manually in Azure AD and configure it when you create the service connection.